# Generate DBContext from designer - complex type unable to cast

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I created My model in designer and generated Database. Entity generated ObjecContext class and others file. I read that i should right click on designer area and select Add Code Generation Item. Next i select EF 5.xDbContext Fluent Generator for C#. i clicked Add and recaive compile error:

> Unable to cas object of type System.Data.Metadara.Edm.ComplexType to
>   type System.Data.Metadata.Edm.PrimiticeType.

I use Entity Framework 5.0 in My WebAPI C# project, i got ComplexType in one of table (created in designer).
How fix it ? Maybe some other way to get dbContext from model-first ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of implementing dbconext is to create a new class and inherit from it. Like

```
public class StudentDbConext : DbConext
{
Public DbSet<Person> {get;set}
}
```